# PowerShell PSCX Read-Archive: Cannot bind parameter... problem

Tags: powershell-2.0, pscx

I'm running across a problem I can't seem to wrap my head around using the Read-Archive cmdlet available via PowerShell Community Extensions (v2.0.3782.38614).

Here is a cut down sample used to exhibit the problem I'm running into:

```
$mainPath = "p:\temp"
$dest = Join-Path $mainPath "ps\CenCodes.zip"
Read-Archive -Path $dest -Format zip
```

Running the above produces the following error:

```
Read-Archive : Cannot bind parameter 'Path'. Cannot convert the "p:\temp\ps\CenCodes.zip" value of type "System.String" to type "Pscx.IO.PscxPathInfo".
At line:3 char:19
+ Read-Archive -Path <<<<  $dest -Format zip
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Read-Archive], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Pscx.Commands.IO.Compression.ReadArchiveCommand
```

If I do not use Join-Path to build the path passed to Read-Archive it works, as in this example:

```
$mainPath = "p:\temp"
$path = $mainPath + "\ps\CenCodes.zip"
Read-Archive -Path $path -Format zip
```

Output from above:

```
    ZIP Folder: CenCodes.zip#\

Index          LastWriteTime         Size    Ratio Name                                                                                       -----          -------------         ----    ----- ----
0         6/17/2010  2:03 AM      3009106  24.53 % CenCodes.xls
```

Even more confusing is if I compare the two variables passed as the Path argument in the two Read-Archive samples above, they seem identical:

This...

```
Write-Host "dest=$dest"
Write-Host "path=$path"
Write-Host ("path -eq dest is " + ($dest -eq $path).ToString())
```

Outputs...

```
dest=p:\temp\ps\CenCodes.zip
path=p:\temp\ps\CenCodes.zip
path -eq dest is True
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why the first sample gripes but the second one works fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an item in the issue tracker on the CodePlex home of PSCX.  Apparently this is a current known issue with PscxPathInfo. (See [item #28023](http://pscx.codeplex.com/workitem/28023) in the PSCX Issue Tracker).

A work around is to do this:

```
Get-Item $dest | Read-Archive
```

Credit to r_keith_hill on CodePlex for that particular work around.